# Firebase Storage in Ionic 2 does not load the image immediately #askfirebase

Tags: angular, ionic2, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use a Firebase Storage stored image in Ionic2 but its not working. The problem is when using ion-tabs. I have it in a separate component (HeaderComponent). It loads on the main open tab but it does not on the other tabs.

```
interface IUser {
  id: string;
  avatar: string;
}

const avatarRef = firebase.storage().ref(this.user.id + "/avatar.jpeg");

avatarRef.getDownloadURL().catch(err => {
  console.log('oh no');
}).then((avatarUrl) => {
  this.user.avatar = avatarUrl;
});

<img [src]="user.avatar">
```

## [Solved]

What I did was that I put the header component in the tabs.html. So the header only loads once in the app. The drawback is that there will probably be a lot of ngIf when it develops more and each tabs will require different functions.

Comment: have you done `console.log(this.user.avatar)` inside then?

Comment: yes and I get the appropriate firebase url

Answer (score 0):

You havent mentioned how you call the method. But you could use `NgZone`

```
constructor(public zone: NgZone){}
```

then in method

```
avatarRef.getDownloadURL().catch(err => {
  console.log('oh no');
}).then((avatarUrl) => {
  this.zone.run(()=>{
    this.user.avatar = avatarUrl;
  })
});
```

you could check [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html) out.

Comment: it's in the constructor so it's called immediately.